# Cypher query for isolating records on time basis

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to do CDR (Call Details Record) Analysis on mobile calls data. Calls are made by a `PERSON`, `THROUGH` a tower and `CONNECTS` to a number. I want to isolate calls that were made prior to a certain date and time and the calling number does not exist after that particular date and time in the records. My current query only shows me data prior to the particular occurrence I am looking for:

```
MATCH (a:PERSON)-[t:THROUGH]->()-[:CONNECTS]->(b)
WHERE toInteger(t.time)<1500399900
RETURN a,b
```

However, how do I now isolate only those records which exist before `t.time=1500399900` and not after that? Also, if I do not limit the above query to say 1000, my browser (Google Chrome), crashes. Any solution for that please?

After running the query as suggested this is what `EXPLAIN` looks like:
[image]

If it helps, this is how I loaded the csv file in neo4j:

```
//Setup initial constraints
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (a:PERSON) assert a.number is unique;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (b:TOWER) assert b.id is unique;

//Create the appropriate nodes
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///combined.csv" AS line
MERGE (a:PERSON {number: line.Calling})
MERGE (b:PERSON {number: line.Called})
MERGE (c:TOWER {id: line.CellID1})


//Setup proper indexing
DROP CONSTRAINT ON (a:PERSON) ASSERT a.number IS UNIQUE;
DROP CONSTRAINT ON (a:TOWER) ASSERT a.id IS UNIQUE;

CREATE INDEX ON :PERSON(number);
CREATE INDEX ON :TOWER(id);

//Create relationships between people and calls
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///combined.csv" AS line
MATCH (a:PERSON {number: line.Calling}),(b:PERSON {number: line.Called}),(c:TOWER {id: line.CellID1})
CREATE (a)-[t:THROUGH]->(c)-[x:CONNECTS]->(b)
SET  x.calltype = line.CallType, x.provider = line.Provider, t.time=toInteger(line.ts), t.duration=toInteger(line.Duration)
```

Comment: How do you identify the calling number? Does each `PERSON` have a single unique number?

Comment: @gabor yes, each person has a unique calling number.

Answer (score 1):

> However, how do I now isolate only those records which exist before `t.time=1500399900` and not after that?

Let's create a small example data set:

```
CREATE 
  (a1:PERSON {name: 'a1'}), (a2:PERSON {name: 'a2'}),
  (b1:PERSON {name: 'b1'}), (b2:PERSON {name: 'b2'}),
  (b3:PERSON {name: 'b3'}), (b4:PERSON {name: 'b4'}),
  (a1)-[:THROUGH {time:  1}]->(:TOWER)-[:CONNECTS]->(b1),
  (a1)-[:THROUGH {time:  3}]->(:TOWER)-[:CONNECTS]->(b2),
  (a2)-[:THROUGH {time:  2}]->(:TOWER)-[:CONNECTS]->(b3),
  (a2)-[:THROUGH {time: 15}]->(:TOWER)-[:CONNECTS]->(b4)
```

It looks like this when visualized:

[image]

This query might do the trick for you:

```
MATCH (a:PERSON)-[t1:THROUGH]->(:TOWER)-[:CONNECTS]->(b:PERSON)
WHERE toInteger(t1.time) < 5
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[t2:THROUGH]->(:TOWER)
WHERE t2.time >= 5
WITH a, b, t1, t2
WHERE t2 IS NULL
RETURN a, b, t1
```

After the first match, it looks for calls of `PERSON` `a` that were initiated after timestamp `5`. There might be no such calls, hence we it uses [`OPTIONAL MATCH`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/optional-match/). The value of `t2` will be null if there were no calls after the specified timestamp, so we do an [`IS NULL`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/operators/#query-operators-comparison) check and return the filtered results.

> Also, if I do not limit the above query to say 1000, my browser (Google Chrome), crashes. Any solution for that please?

If you use the graph visualizer, it usually cannot render more than a few hundred nodes. Possible workarounds:

- Use the **Text** view of the web browser that scales better.
- Paginate by using [`SKIP ... LIMIT ...`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/skip/#skip-return-middle-rows).

Comment: I am afraid that doesn't work. Gives me zero results. I tried this problem in `R` and was able to get roughly 82,000 results. The total number of observations are a little over 200,000.

Comment: There are at least two things that I might did not get right: 1. I reused variable `a` for the second match. Instead, you could reuse its "`number`" property somehow: `MATCH (:PERSON {number: a.number})-[t2:THROUGH]->(:TOWER)` 2. Is my interpretation correct for checking `THROUGH` relationships with `time >= 1500399900` correct?

Comment: I am trying your suggestion and yes, your assumption on `THROUGH` is correct. It has a property called `time` associated with it. Also, I am trying your suggestion but wrapping `t2.time` in `toInteger()`. Taking forever to run...

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas probably just needs an `OPTIONAL` match

Comment: @aldrin very good point. I updated my answer accordingly and added an example.

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas and @aldrin thank you so much for your suggestions. However, even with the `OPTIONAL` match, the query has been running for  over an hour now. I know there are only 80,000 records there. But its still going on. No clue why.

Comment: Can you run the query with the `EXPAIN ...` prefix? This will not execute the query itself but show an estimation of the cardinalities for each execution step. You can export the plan as a PNG file and share it in your question -- just make sure it does not have any sensitive data.

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas added the `EXPLAIN` output.

Comment: I did not get a chance to look into this during weekdays. Did you make any progress? I'll look into it on Sunday if you're still stuck.